# Single Sign On between sites hosted in windows server and azure cloud

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have 3 ASP.NET MVC websites sharing the same domain.

1. one.domain.com
2. two.domain.com
3. three.domain.com

These websites are exposed to customers. Customer need to log in to each website separately. I wish to provide common log in for all these sites using Single Sign On(SSO) so that if the customer is logged into one site, he/she will be automatically logged into other 2 sits also.

Website #1 and 2 are hosted in Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine with Windows Server OS(purchased VM) and website #3 is hosted in MS Azure cloud. How to implement Single Sign On between websites 1/2 and 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on Azure Active Directory as Identity Provider for you users and integrate your different apps with it as a authentication mechanism.

You have examples of MVC applications integrated with AD [in this offical Github Repo.](https://github.com/AzureADSamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=webapp) and [the Developer Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-developers-guide/) with explanations about the platform and how to integrate with different technologies.